# android set TextView to html file

Tags: android, html, arrays, string, http

I need to get information from this website: http://rowans.diekantankys.nl/bonnen/index.php?id=4 (It's in dutch)
From line 36 and on is a table in which you can see the debt op people on this website:

```
<td>Marc</td>
<td>16.75</td>
</tr> <tr>
<td>Marlieke</td>
<td>7.27</td>
</tr> <tr>
<td>Anne Ruth</td>
<td>4.70</td>
```

but all the functions and methods that I found that should download an HTML file from a website/web-server to a string/array somehow fail, can anyone give me a method on which I can give my full error report?

My apology's if this is considered: "Not a real question", I don't know how to formulate this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use (http://jsoup.org "JSoup") to download the parse the `HTML` from `URL`

You can get the `HTML` as `document` and read the text on the `elements`

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://rowans.diekantankys.nl/bonnen/index.php?id=4").get();
```

In you case on this website , you need to get the `text` in the table body i.e., `tbody`

```
String table = doc.body().getElementsByTag("tbody").text()
```

So, you need to download the content first in an `background thread` and then update the `TextView` on `UIThread`.

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Long>(){
        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                final Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://rowans.diekantankys.nl/bonnen/index.php?id=4").get();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        String tableContent = doc.body().getElementsByTag("tbody").text();
                        // you can split the text and read it, as required.
                        textView.setText(tableContent);
                    }
                });

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
```

Hope it helps you. Let me know if any issue.

Comment: This should work, but where in my class should I put this? I want to get the html file on a button click called getSchuld(); (http://pastebin.com/uBL4K2GN)

Comment: Add this inside getSchuld(), hope this is the method called when the button clicked.else add a on click listener to the button and call the method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download all the HTML content, put it into a string and parse manually the code. If you are interested in the values into that table, I would suggest you to search into the string that contains the downloaded HTML for a uniqui piece of string that identifies the beginning of the table (eg. search for '' tag and you put the HTML section of code of the table into a different variable. Then you proceed to parse manually that string searching for  and  and extracting the values with a loop. Another way would be use regular expressions but it becames more difficult if you're not faimiliar with them. It's not a relevant resource but in this android app, I did exactly what just explained https://github.com/rexromae/mytotem_android/blob/master/com.torvergata.mytotem/src/com/torvergata/mytotem/student/StudentLogin.java